# problems with longtable and multirow

Tags: longtable, multirow

I have an issue using multirow and longtable. The content in the multirow cell is very large, and it goes well beyond the limit of the "non-multirowed" rows. LaTeX ignores that and starts the following row just behind those rows, therefore overwriting the content.

Hereafter a minimum working code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{0.65\textwidth}|}
    \hline  
    1 & 1.1 & \multirow{3}{.65\textwidth} {\lipsum[1] }\\
     & 1.2 & \\
     & 1.3 & \\ \hline  
     2 & 2.1 & \lipsum[2] \\ \hline  
     \end{longtable} 
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Any help is truly appreciated ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can find something useful in the answers to one of the following closely related questions: [Multirow cell content overflows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343779/134144), [Tabularx text bleeds into next row with multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436382/134144), [How to stop multirow text to overlap the next row?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434999/134144),

Answer (score 1):

I am still unsure what you are looking for, but based on your last comments regarding adding `vspace`, I am curious why you do not place the section number (1.1, 1.2 and 1.3) in the same cell i column 2. The cells in the third columns will then shrink and expand automatically if you add or delete text. If you have rows where two sections contain text, you place that section in a separate row, see example 2.

Two additional improvements:

1. Remove the `centering`-environment. [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is centred by default, and use its own alignment algorithm (see documentation)
2. Calculate the rows by taking into account the influence of `tabcolsep`s and the width of vertical rules, see the new preamble. If you have several similar tables, I recommend that you load [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and define two new column-types using `\newcolumntype`, which you then may use in the your tables’ preambles:

---

```
\newcolumntype{M}{p{\dimexpr(0.175\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth)}}
\newcolumntype{N}{p{\dimexpr(0.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)}}
```

The preamble for the first tabular:

```
 \begin{longtable}{|M|M|N|}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
|p{\dimexpr(0.175\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth)}
|p{\dimexpr(0.175\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth)}
|p{\dimexpr(0.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)}|}
\hline  
1 & 1.1 \par 1.2\par 1.3 & \lipsum[1]\\\hline  
 2 & 2.1 & \lipsum[2] \\ \hline  
 \end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

---

For certain, I would have chosen a different layout, using [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) rules and no vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum, array}

\newcolumntype{O}{p{\dimexpr(0.175\linewidth-1.5\tabcolsep)}}
\newcolumntype{P}{p{\dimexpr(0.65\linewidth-\tabcolsep)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}OOP@{}}
    \toprule \addlinespace[1ex]
    1 & 1.1 \par 1.2\par 1.3 & \lipsum[1]\\\midrule  \addlinespace[1ex]
    2 & 2.1 & \lipsum[2] \\\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){3-3}
      & 2.2\par 2.3 & \lipsum[2] \\ \midrule
     \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I only have 3 subsection, not 19, or 40. So I'm sorry but this answer does not really help my case. As well, I know that adding a \vspace (*) makes the table look correct, but I wonder if there is a better/nicer way to get this done? (*) ->  \vspace{6.8cm} & 1.3 & \\ \hline

Comment: @alexb If you describe what you are looking for, maybe you can get better answers.  "...but I wonder if there is a better/nicer way to get this done? " was not what you asked for in your question. (More precisely, you did not ask a questions at all!)

Comment: in my example the text in the third column goes well over the multirow. As I have only 3 subsections and a description that is for the three of them, I simply cannot add a random number of lines (or subsection) as in your answer, to make the last cell fit. One solution I've found is to use \vspace, but it's a hack as every time I change the text I need to update the space manually. So I am wondering if anyone knows a proper solution, where from proper I mean that LaTeX automatically put the following row below the content of the last cell.

Comment: Thanks! the reason why I had different rows is because the table is quite long, repeated 16 times, so I was using the same layout and adding the text in the last column. In most cases the text is different for every line but in a few places has to be merged together. Indeed I can change the few times where it happens so I don't have this issue.

Comment: @alexb I have updated the code and added some additional tips to simplify the code. If the answer has been to help, consider to accept the it, and eventually upvote. If it has been of no help, I will consider deleting it.